# My feedforward network is giving me an output averaging what I really want

Tags: c++, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am building a feed forward network from scratch and have the following problem:
I have 4 neurons in entry and 4 as exit, the input is `[x;x;x;x]`
with x being either a 0 or a 1 the output must be the same as the input.

After training over 1 million entries and 1000 batch the result I get is always around `[0.5;0.5;0.5;0.5]`.

I tried changing the number of epoch and the number of entries.

Since 0.5 is the mean of 0 and 1, I think their must be a logic answer to my problem

Edit: I resolved the problem by debugging my weight changes,

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Do you have a question? You seem to have forgotten to ask it. Also as your troubles are most likely due to a bug in your code, you might have to add a version of your code that demonstrates the problem you are having to the question as well. See the explanation at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

There is many reasons for this behavior. The most common is that your nn has too small capability. NN model want to minimalize cost function if there is not possibility to adjust to modeled function shape nn will average function which is the normal and the best strategy in this kind of optimization. The second explanation could be that your data dont have any pattern inside. Random inputs force NN to return mean of distribution.

I suggest you to increase capability of network by adding hidden layer with additional neurons (i.e 50, 100, 200 neurons hidden layer) and observe what happens. Be careful with adding more than one hidden layer if you don't use 'relu' activation functions because of gradient vanishing problem.